# ImageView as background for Activity not showing on API23 (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have set ImageView as background for my Activity layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/default_bg_welcome"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <!-- My content -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Works great for API <23, but somehow on Android 6.0, the background shows as white. Removed any theme for the activity in Manifest, still the same. Has anybody had this issue? Any ideas what might have gone wrong?

Comment: are you trying to set the background for layout?

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/default_bg_welcome"` try this

Comment: @AkhilJayakumar but this cannot let me use center crop so easily. I want to use ImageView, as it is more customizable and have used it like this for long. Just want to have relative layout over the ImageView. Can this be done, anyhow on Android 6.0?

Comment: just try to adjust the width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with API 23 and that works well for me...later on it depends on your image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/male"
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_giftsharealert_propic"
                    />
     </LinearLayout>
```

or else you can set this line in your parent layout

```
android:background="@drawable/male"
```

Comment: Thanx. The problem was in my image, yes. Somehow just it did not show on Android 6.0. Probably it was too large. Thanx a lot for everybody, stupid mistake, that did not test another image.

Answer (score 0):

Try set Background in layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/yourbackground"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/default_bg_welcome"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- My content -->

</RelativeLayout>
```